# Effective ways to calculate multivariable taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I need to calculate first 20 members of taylor series for $e^{x^7+y^{11} \cos{(x^{10}+y^8})}$. Are there any ways except the terrible direct way.

Comment: By hand?${{{}}}$

Comment: By calculating all partial derivatives directly.
It seems to be very difficult.